# collision detection of controls and inner boundary of screen (view)

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I am making a simple application for win 8, In which user can move controls (BUTTONS etc), How to detect when buttons collide each other and how to detect that button is colliding with inner boundary of screen?  Kindly Help me with this !

Answer (score 0):

From my game programming experience, I would imagine you would do a check using the position and size of both objects to determine if there is an intersection, and hence, a collision taking place.
Probably do that on the object moved event. Cycle through your entire collection of objects and do the intersection check.

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve and haven't got windows 8, but the principle should still be valid.

Comment: I understand, but I am having trouble visualising what you are doing. For example how you are storing your objects, how you are moving them, what your interface is like and generally what kind of application you are building. I can't give you much more than a general answer without knowing more about what you are trying to do.